# Passing Multiple Objects To WatchKit In A NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, watchkit

With the help of some great tutorials and users here, I've had success implementing SwiftyJSON in my app and getting a basic WatchKit app built alongside.  My last hurdle to pass is getting my whole set of parsed JSON data to be passed to WatchKit, as to allow me to choose from a cell in a TableView and pull up more specific detail on a piece of criteria.

I'm parsing JSON data in my **Minion.swift** file, like so;

```
import UIKit

class Minion {

    var name: String?
    var age: String?
    var height: String?
    var weight: String?


    class func fetchMinionData() -> [Minion] {
        let dataURL = NSURL(string: "http://myurl/json/")

        var dataError: NSError?

        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: dataURL!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &dataError)


        let minionJSON = JSONValue(data)
        var minions = [Minion]()

       for minionDictionary in minionJSON {
           minions.append(Minion(minionDetails: minionDictionary))
        }

        return minions 
    }

    init(minionDetails: JSONValue) {
        name = minionDetails["san"].string
        age = minionDetails["age"].string
        height = minionDetails["height"].string
        weight = minionDetails["free"].string
    }
}
```

For my iOS app, this is working well to populate my UITableView and subsequent Detail View.  I have my **ViewController.Swift** like so;

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    let minions: [Minion]

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        minions = Minion.fetchMinionData()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.mygroup.data")
        let key = "dashboardData"
        defaults?.setObject(minions, forKey: key)
        defaults?.synchronize()
    }

// MARK: Table view data source
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

}
```

I've truncated much of the code as I don't believe it's relevant to WatchKit.  In the WatchKit extension, I have my **InterfaceController.swift** like so;

```
import WatchKit

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    @IBOutlet weak var minionTable: WKInterfaceTable!

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.mygroup.data")

    var dashboardData: String? {
        defaults?.synchronize()
        return defaults?.stringForKey("dashboardData")
    }

    let minions = ???
```

When I run the iOS app, it throws me the error "Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType')" because I am passing the whole set of JSON data as "minions."  If I set my NSUserDefaults key to "minions[0].name" it will pass the single string, but passing the whole set of data so the WatchKit table can allow me to choose a row seems to be evading me.

In advance, as always, I am most grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Minion` class need to implement the `NSCoding`. Then in your view controller you need to transfer your `Minion` object to `NSData` object.

```
 class Minion: NSObject, NSCoding  {
    .....
    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
      aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name")
      aCoder.encodeObject(age, forKey: "age")
      aCoder.encodeObject(height, forKey: "height")
      aCoder.encodeObject(weight, forKey: "weight")
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
       name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as String
       age = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("age") as String
       height = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("height") as String
       weight = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("weight") as String
    }
}
```

In your ViewController class:

```
  NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName("Minion", forClass: Minion.self)
  defaults?.setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(minions), forKey: "minions")
```

If you want to retrieve the data from `NSUserDefaults`:

```
if let data = defaults?.objectForKey("minions") as? NSData {
    NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(Minion.self, forClassName: "Minion")
    let minions = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! [Minion]
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ztan!  I think this is exactly what I'm looking for.  Just to clarify, the first code block you presented would go in my "Minions.swift" file, correct?  I got thrown some errors that the type does not conform to NSCoding, but I'll investigate further.

Comment: Yes, the first block is for your `Minion.swift` file.

Comment: Thanks @ztan!  I think I'm very close, and your guidance is exemplary.  I'm sorry to keep bothering, but was hoping you could advise what to do with the last block of code you provided me.  Would I be placing this in my InterfaceController.swift in my WatchKit extension?  I seem to be having trouble finding the right placement/verbiage to set the minions variable to the NSData object set in my WatchKit InterfaceController.  Again, thanks!

Comment: @AlanLewis, the very last block of code should be placed in the `InterfaceController.swift` file in your WatchKit extension, if you want to display the data in your watch. You can place that code in the `override func willActivate()` method. So you can retrieve the `NSUserDefaults` data, when your watch interface going to display to the user.

Comment: Thanks @ztan.  I'm still hitting errors with implementing `if let data = ud.objectForKey("minions") as? NSData {` in my project, with Xcode reporting _italic_Use of unresolved identifier 'ud'_italic_.  Since I'm not referencing "ud" anywhere else in my project, I tried `if let data = defaults?.objectForKey("minions") as? NSData {` which seemed to eradicate that error, but subsequently told me that my "minions" is inferred to have type 'AnyObject?' which may be unexpected.

Comment: Ah, I'm so close @ztan!  I appreciate your edit and have implemented your change to `InterfaceController.swift` in my WatchKit extension.  This did successfully eradicate my errors, though my WatchKit app now crashes at launch with `NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class`...Since I hadn't done it before, I imported my Minion.swift and SwiftyJSON.swift files into my WatchKit extension (since they weren't there), though that didn't help.  I'm starting to wonder if what I'm passing from the iOS app is more the issue than the WatchKit side.

Comment: @AlanLewis, please my updated answer, hope that will help. If not you might try to delete the app in your simulator first, clean cache. Also, try to retrieve the data from your phone side, see if that works.

Comment: @AlanLewis,  If you found my answer solved your problem, would you mind marking it as accepted (green checkmark)?